# How to htaccess url rewrite multi language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can someone help me with the htaccess rewrite url?

1. I need to convert **?lang=en** to **/en**
2. To always display the language used in the url
3. When someone comes to **example.com** to automatically 301 redirect them
   to **example.com/en** as the main language.
4. When a user chooses another language to stay on the same page e.g.
   **example.com/en/contact.php**

I have a total of three languages on the site en, de, hr.

The problem with my code is when I go to example.com/contact and select a language, it takes me back to the homepage example.com/en. If I type manually example.com/en/contact it works.

If I am at example.com/en/contact and choose another language e.g. /de url changes to example.com/en/de and a 404 error.

My current htaccess code looks like this

```
# Convert ?lang=en in /en
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ ?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([bs|en|de]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

# Remove trailing slash from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Remove php extension in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)reg\.bmi\.id$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://reg.bmi.id [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\scontact/contact\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://reg.bmi.id [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ contact/contact.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried, but I get error 500.
Something seems to be wrong with this piece of code:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\scontact/contact\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://reg.bmi.id [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ contact/contact.php [NC,L]`
I have listed the "contact" page just for example. If the user is on the "About us" or "Contact us" page and decides to change the language, he should stay on the current page.